# how to analyse multiple GLMMs?

Tags: r, comparison, lme4, mixed-models

I would like to analyse my data using multiple glmms at once. Here is a dummy example;

```
library(lme4)
library(broom)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

pstar <- function(x,bonf=1){
    lab <- rep('',length(x))
    x[is.na(x)] <- 1
    lab[x<0.1/bonf] <- '*'
    lab[x<0.05/bonf] <- '**'
    lab[x<0.01/bonf] <- '***'
    lab
}

IVs <- c('gen','rack','nutrient')
RE <- 'popu'
DV <- 'total.fruits'

data(Arabidopsis)
Arabidopsis[Arabidopsis$total.fruits<1,'total.fruits'] <- 1 # because I work with a Gamma distribution

form <- as.formula(paste(DV, paste(c(IVs,paste("(1 |",RE,")")), collapse = " + "), sep = " ~ ")) # nonsensical for this data

mods <- dlply(Arabidopsis,c('reg'),function(x) glmer(form, family = Gamma(link = "log"), data=x))
modstidy <- ldply(mods,tidy)
modstidy <- ddply(modstidy,c('reg'), transform, sig=pstar(p.value,length(unique(reg))))

ggplot(modstidy[modstidy$group=='fixed',],aes(y=term,x=reg))+
    geom_tile(aes(fill=estimate))+
    geom_text(aes(label=sig))
```

The goal is to answer questions such as "given I have these values for the IVs, in what region should I plant?". Some regions are expected to be highly sensitive to certain variables whereas others are not. So it's important to estimate the effect of each variable by region.

The problem is that I have at least 20 'regions'. By employing a bonferroni correction (p-values/20) most of the IVs that were highly significant are not anymore or barely so. Also, it's pretty inconvenient to do the model selection and present the residual patterns, etc. for over 20 models.

Can I improve this approach somehow or should I do something completely different? Because the relationship is best modeled using a random effect and gamma distribution, I haven't found another way of dealing with this data.

-- EXTRA INFO --

In reality I have error estimates (DV) associated to +20 methodological approaches, applied twice (RE) to data for different species with diverse characteristics (IVs). If I work on a given species, what approach should I use?

Comment: This seems like more of a statistical question than a programming question--I'd suggest migrating to stat.stackexchange.

Comment: Initial thoughts: Do you really think that your different regions are so independent that you don't want share *any* information between them? It seems also like you're scaling the IVs overall, combining all regions, which seems fishy given the independent models per region.

Comment: Thanks. I put it here because there might be suggestions specific to R. The 'regions' are in reality different statistical approaches and in my opinion rather independent and the envelope of methods considered should not affect the output. For the scaling I made a mistake in this dummy example.

Comment: Perhaps then you can be more specific about your question. *"Can I improve this approach somehow or should I do something completely different?"* sounds like you're asking for statistical advice about methods. Are you meaning to ask about how to streamline your code? It's not so many lines of code, no glaring inefficiencies jump out.

Comment: Generally, I think questions along the lines of "what should I do?" go on stats.stackexchange, where questions that are "how do I do X in R?" go here. You are looking for advice on what you should do.